# Access Validation If Value don't exist one table can't be entered in another

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two tables in access, one is the main table that contains invoices, that is called `tblinvoices`. The invoice number is in the `inv` field. The other is where we route invoices and it is called `tblroute`. The invoice field name is the same. If a user enters an invoice number in the inv field in the `tblroute` that does not exist in `thetblinvoices` inv field.

I would like it prompt invoice number does not exist.

I have tried all types of code to render desired results
Code:

```
Private Sub INV__BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

 Dim Answer As Variant
 Answer = DLookup("[inv]", "tblinvoices", "[inv] = '" & Me.inv & "'")
 If IsNull(Answer) Then
 MsgBox "Invoice number does not exist!!" & vbCrLf & "PLease ipdate invoice tables.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly + vbDefaultButton1, "Invalid Invoice#"

 Cancel = True
 Me.inv.Undo


 Else:
 End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the error message show correctly?

Comment: NO it does not show, it just continues to the next row.

Comment: Have you checked that that this piece of code is being run?  Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the first row of code and checking that the event is being fired?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your invoice number is *numeric*, thus no quotes:

```vb
Answer = DLookup("[inv]", "tblinvoices", "[inv] = " & Me.inv & "")
```

Comment: No error is prompted when the user enters an invoice number that does not exist:(

Comment: If so, Answer _will_ be _Null_. So, something else is going on.